# Azure IoT Hub trigger Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am a newbie with Azure and I want to send a message periodically from Raspberry Pi to Azure IoT Hub then trigger Azure Function (instead of using Stream Analystic) and then save the message to the database. I have seen some online tutorials but I have found that this tutorial is old and only uses C#. And I want to use Python because I am familiar with this language. Is there any updated Azure Function tutorial using Python? Or could you guy please give me an example?

Thanks in advance to those who can enlighten me!

Comment: check this [blog](https://tlaothong.gitbooks.io/azure-iot-workshop/content/iot-hub-store-data-in-azure-table-storage.html), this is similar to your requirement, but it is in node.js. I think you can easily convert it into python as it's just a basic code.

Comment: @SaiKarri-MT Thank you. I am gonna try this now

Comment: Hi, after trying, I realize that, my Azure is using Linux and some configurations are missing in compare to Azure Windows. Do you know any tutorial for Azure Linux? @SaiKarri-MT

Comment: Hi Anh Tu, Azure function python will use consumption plan with Linux as OS. Refer to this [doc](https://azurelessons.com/azure-functions-in-python/#:~:text=Create%20a%20Python%20Azure%20Function%20Project%20using%20Visual,choose%20the%20Authorization%20level%20based%20on%20your%20requirement.) to create Python Azure function in VSCode.

Comment: @SaiKarri-MT But how can I configure the output of the function? I want to save it in Azure database

Comment: You can get that from [Azure Table Storage Output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table). When you create a trigger from VSCode in your local, these bindings are located in function.json file. You can modify them accordingly by referring to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement you can follow the below steps:

1. Create Storage Account with your resource group.
2. Go to IoT Hub and get the connection string.
3. Create a consumer group for IoT Hub.
4. Install VS Code and install all the Azure related Extensions.
5. Go to Function App in VS Code and Create a new function app.
6. Select the Interpreter as Python.
7. Select any one of the trigger (**EventHubTrigger**). Provide required inputs related to event hub.
8. At input and output of function app, configure it accordingly to table storage as target. Refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=python) and below is the sample binding trigger:

   ```
    {
      "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
      "bindings": [
        {
          "name": "message",
          "type": "table",
          "tableName": "messages",
          "partitionKey": "message",
          "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
          "direction": "out"
        },
        {
          "authLevel": "function",
          "type": "httpTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "name": "req",
          "methods": [
            "get",
            "post"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "http",
          "direction": "out",
          "name": "$return"
        }
      ]
    }
   ```
9. Add your basic logic python code and test it.
10. After successful execution, deploy the function to Azure from VS Code.
11. Add local.settings.json keys and values to Configuration --> Application settings in your function app.

You can achieve your task with these steps, If you find any difficulty in any of the step, you can go through the MS documentation related to it.

Comment: I have some questions: 1) As I understood, in order to connect Azure IoT Hub with Azure Function, I have to configure the function.json data, but I don't know which one in this json data should be configure? 2) Same question for database, which one in function.json data should be configured to save message to database?